# Union All - Does not use all thread

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different queries. (both are View having sub queries in it)

Query A: select * from View_A

Query B: select * from View_B

If I run any of these two queries individually, both return the result in less than a second.

But if I do simple "Union ALL" between these two queries, it takes more than 12 seconds to return the result.

I analyzed the Query execution Plan and found that when it is "Union", View_A does not use all the threads while executing.

And if I run View_A individually it uses all threads and returns the result in less than 1 sec.

Following is the screenshot of the Execution plan where we can see the difference.

Why this is happening with Union All?

[image]

Comment: This subject is much more complicated than just why. First you should know that views do no have their own execution plan, it depends on usage and underlying queries, and there are tons of factors that could play in sql server deciding to use parallelism or not.
Google: "SQL Server parallelism" to learn more on subjects. Red-gate has a nice article.

Answer (score 0):

Don't paste screenshots of your execution plans, instead upload them to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and link them in your Post. They contain a lot of information encoded in them that's not visible in a screenshot.

In SQL Server, there is no guarantee that all threads will be used, or evenly distributed, when parallelism appears in a query plan. In fact, it's pretty common that all threads don't get used.

Please see [Uneven query executions with parallelism](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/uneven-query-executions-with-parallelism/ba-p/317495) for more information which states:

> When your query is compiled with parallelism, there is no guarantee that it will be executed with multiple threads.

Please also see [Skewing Parallelism For Fun And Profit](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/skewing-parallelism-for-fun-and-profit/) for further in depth information on some of the underlying causes of this issue.

Comment: I am aware of uploading the plan, but since it was larger than 2 mb I could not upload.

Comment: It does not allow more than 2 mb. The same is mentioned on their website too. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/

Comment: @Teknas Ah that's unfortunate. How huge of query do you have lol? I have execution plans with hundreds of operators, and have yet to hit that limitation.

Comment: @Teknas Also, please let me know if anything is unclear in my answer.